# {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method"} in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, api, rest, syntax-error, status

I've managed to setup the REST ful API in my Codeigniter Application.name of controller and name of method are different but `{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method"}` error was display,how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Call the domain/index.php/controller/function without the "_get" .For example if your controller is called api and the function is users_get, use the address
localhost/domain/index.php/api/users.

That should work fine.